# Radius of convergence of $\frac{e^z}{1+z}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

> Show that $$\frac{e^{z}}{1+z} = 1 + \frac{1}{2} z^2 - \frac{1}{3} z^3 + \frac{3}{8} z^4 - \frac{11}{30} z^5 + ...$$ Show that the general term of the power series is given by $$a_n = (-1)^n \left[ \frac{1}{2!} - \frac{1}{3!} + ... + \frac{(-1)^n}{n!} \right], ~~~~~ n \ge 2$$ What is the radius of convergence of this series?

The only thing I'm having trouble with is determining the radius of convergence. My thought is that the geometric series converges on the disc $|z| < 1$, so the radius of convergence should be at least $1$. Is that correct to say? But I want to argue that it's actually equal to $1$. Can I just simply say that any larger disc would contain $z=-1$ and $\frac{e^{z}}{1+z}$ is not defined at it? Or do I have to find a point $z_0$ in a larger disc centered at $z=0$, and argue that the series $$1 + \frac{1}{2} z_0^2 - \frac{1}{3} z_0^3 + \frac{3}{8} z_0^4 - \frac{11}{30} z_0^5 + ...$$ diverges? If so, what's the easiest way to do that? Show that the coefficients don't converge to $0$? Come to think of it, it doesn't look like the coefficents would go to $0$ for any point $z_0$ outside of the unit disc.

Comment: What is $\lim |a_n|$ as $n\to\infty$?

Comment: The radius of convergence of a power series is the distance to the singularity closest to origin of corresponding function.

Comment: @achillehui Ah, I think my professor mentioned this theorem in class. So, we are looking at the singularities of $\frac{e^{z}}{1+z}$, right, which has a singularity at $z=-1$.

Comment: Yup, this means the radius of convergence is $1$.`

Answer (score 1):

We apply the ratio test to the power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}a_{n}z^{n}$ to find:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggr|\frac{a_{n+1}z^{n+1}}{a_{n}z^{n}}\biggr|
=
|z|\lim_{n\to\infty}\biggr|1-\frac{(-1)^{n}}{(n+1)n!}\frac{1}{|a_{n}|}\biggr|
$$
To evaluate this limit, note that the power series definition of $e^{z}$ gives $\lim_{n\to\infty}|a_{n}|=e^{-1}$. Can you take it from here?